# Is it right that $\{2x : x \in\mathbb{Z}, |x| < 4\} = \{−6,−4,−2,0,2,4,6\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I just started reading some book where it explicitly says that
$\left\{2x : x \in\mathbb{Z}, |x| < 4\right\} =$ $\left\{−6,−4,−2,0,2,4,6\right\}$

But that's how I tried to solve it and I had different answer:

$2x: x \in\mathbb{Z}$ which means, *the set of all things in the form $2x$ such that $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$*
$\left\{..., -10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, ...\right\}$

Then we have $|x| < 4$, which scales down the previous set to a range of only $[-2, 2]$, so if the set contains $\left\{-6, -4, 4, 6\right\}$ they're all proved to be wrong because their absolutes are all $≥ 4$.

So the correct set should actually only be $\left\{-2, 0, 2\right\}$ according to my understanding.
[image: Book Of Proof by Richard Hammack: Page 16]

But Page 16 of Book Of Proof by Richard Hammack has a different solution with no explanation

I'm quite new to these set expressions so please tell me if I interpreted anything wrong.

Comment: $x$ is said to be an integer number with absolute value less then $4$. Thus $x$ is an integer ranging from $-3$ to $3$. Thus your set (made of elements of the form $2x$) is indeed that of the book.

Comment: The set of those number $n$ such that : $n=2x$ for $|x| < 4$. Thus, starting generating the set of $x$ such that ... i.e. the set containing : $-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$ and then produce the set of $n=2x$.

Comment: @AlbertoSaracco Ohh!! Can you please write an answer? I'll upvote it cause your comment really helped me a lot..  and I just got it all mixed, really sorry. Didn't think it was all just that

Comment: Done. @Beyondo: the point is to ask question when confused... The wrong thing to do is to keep the doubt or hold the wrong idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ is said to be an integer number with absolute value less then $4$. Thus $x$ is an integer ranging from $−3$ to $3$. Thus your set (made of elements of the form $2x$) is indeed that of the book.

Answer (score 1):

You are only told that $|x| <4$, not that $|2x| <4$. So $|2x|$ can go up to $8$ and the given answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You did solve another problem:
$$\{x \mid x \in\mathbb{Z}, |2x| < 4\}.$$
Here the solution is your solution $\{−2,0,2\}$.

But you should split the problem into two parts. First find the set of values for $x$:
$$x \in S := \{x \mid x \in \mathbb Z, |x| < 4\}.$$
This are all integers with absolute value less than four: $x \in \{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3\}$.

Then map this set with the function $f(x) = 2x$:
$$\{2x \mid x \in S\} = \{-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6\}.$$